# Multiple download file using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a site that allows the user to download a set of images based on user selection. How can I have downloads of multiple files? is it possible to download more than 1 file at a time?

If it is only possible to download 1 file at a time, how can I "create" 5 files, get them zipped, and let the user download that product zip file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do only one download at a time.

If you like to zip the files have a look at [this](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/09/force-download-mutiple-files-zip-archive-php.html).

You can create the files using [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)().

**Update**

On second thought... Maybe you are able to start multiple downloads if you open a new tab/window for each file. But the browser might block those popups:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('download.php?name=file1','_newtab');
    window.open('download.php?name=file2','_newtab');
    window.open('download.php?name=file3','_newtab');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download a lof of zipped file formats, look at this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php

Answer (score 0):

You can't download multiple files. You have to zip them and redirect the user's browers on the zip.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PHP ZIP class to suit your needs.

This code creates a zip archive for you:

```
    <?php
function createZipFile($files = array(), $filePath){
    // Check if $files we had contains files
    if(is_array($files)){
        // $files contains files, loop through them
        foreach($files as $file){
            // Does the file exist?
            if(file_exists($file)){
                $filesToBeZipped[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }

    if(count($filesToBeZipped)){
        // Create your new zip archive
        $zipArchive = new ZipArchive();
        if($zipArchive->open($filePath, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true){
            return false;
        }else{
            foreach($filesToBeZipped as $file) {
                $zipArchive->addFile($file,$file);
            }

            $zipArchive->close();
            return file_exists($filePath);
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

$files = array(
  'filename1.extension',
  '/path/to/filename/filename.extension',
);

$action = createZipFile($files,'yourSampleArchive.zip');
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Php can only send one file at a time, but you can generate javascript code with php which calls multiple php files.